# passing value from callback to callback in Plotly dash application

Tags: python, callback, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

i have a dash application with a plotly graph i have two callbacks i want to get input from the user store it with dcc.store in the variable with id 'stkName-value' and call it in the other callback. I want to be able to get the user input and use it in the callback function update_graph_live how would i do this please help

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, callback, State
app = Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    
    dcc.Graph(id='graph'),
    dcc.Interval(
        id='interval',
        interval=inter,
        n_intervals=0,
      ),

    html.Div(dcc.Input(id='input-on-submit', type='text')),
    html.Button('Submit', id='submit-val', n_clicks=0),
    html.Div(id='container-button-basic',children='Enter a value and press submit'),

    dcc.Store(id='stkName-value')
    
    

])

@callback(
    Output('stkName-value', 'data'),
    Output('container-button-basic', 'children'),
    Input('submit-val', 'n_clicks'),
    State('input-on-submit', 'value'),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)

def update_output(n_clicks, value):
    value = str(value).upper() 
    if value in symbols:
        print('The input symbol was "{}" '.format(value))
        return str(value).upper(), str(value).upper()
    else:
        return 'The input symbol was '+str(value)+' is not accepted please try different symbol ', 'The input symbol was '+str(value)+' is not accepted please try different symbol '

@callback(Output('graph', 'figure'),
          Input('interval', 'n_intervals'))

def update_graph_live(n_intervals):
...
return figure
```

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 1224, in dispatch
    args_grouping = map_grouping(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dash/_grouping.py", line 124, in map_grouping
    return [map_grouping(fn, g) for g in grouping]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dash/_grouping.py", line 124, in <listcomp>
    return [map_grouping(fn, g) for g in grouping]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dash/_grouping.py", line 129, in map_grouping
    return fn(grouping)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 1225, in <lambda>
    lambda ind: inputs_state[ind], inputs_state_indices
IndexError: list index out of range
```

```
when i add the the store value to the second callback i am getting this error only when i run it in google cloud but it runs fine on my local machine can some tell me what the issue is causing this?
```

Comment: maybe you should do all in one function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `State()` for the store in the second callback, just as for the 'input-on-submit' component value in the first callback :

```py
@callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    Input('interval', 'n_intervals'),
    State('stkName-value', 'data')
)
def update_graph_live(n_intervals, data):
    # ...
    return figure
```

The function will still be triggered by the interval input, but it will receive the current store data as well.

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range i get an IndexError when i do this

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 1225, in <lambda>
    lambda ind: inputs_state[ind], inputs_state_indices
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: "_I get an IndexError when i do this_" ... when you do what ? Taking your code and replacing the 2nd callback with the code above should only throw `NameError: name 'figure' is not defined` (obviously), the error might come from the code you added responsible for creating the plotly figure, but it might just as well come from anywhere else, the thing is we can't guess if you don't show the edits you made in the meantime nor the relevant part of the error message. Anyway, all this should belong to another question as this one has been answered and the issue you got now is not directly related.

Comment: Nb. By "the relevant part of the error message" I meant the whole thing in fact, that is,  with the stack trace.

Comment: not sure why but i am only getting the indexError when i am running on google cloud but it runs fine locally

Answer (score 1):

You can use the store data as an input for a callback as well.  Once the store is updated, the second callback is triggered.

```
@callback(Output('graph', 'figure'),
          Input('stkName-value', 'data'),
          Input('interval', 'n_intervals')
          )
def update_graph_live(data, n_intervals):
    ...
    return fig
```

Comment: the update_graph_live is suppose to update every 2 mins are you saying that it wont update until we get the input from the user and store it?

Comment: @smith You can have the interval as an input.  You can have stkName-value be an Input or a State, depending on whether you want it to trigger the update on the user update or just on the interval.

Comment: i get this error  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dash/_grouping.py", line 129, in map_grouping
    return fn(grouping)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 1225, in <lambda>
    lambda ind: inputs_state[ind], inputs_state_indices
IndexError: list index out of range" do you know why